# WTForms datetime field time is not updating

Tags: python, time, wtforms, pytz

I have wtforms defined for datetime field as below:

```
stime = DateTimeField(label='Start time',validators=[validators.InputRequired()],format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M",default= datetime.now(timezone('UTC')))
    etime = DateTimeField(label='End time',validators=[validators.InputRequired()],format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M",default= datetime.now(timezone('UTC')))
```

On HTML page calling this fields as below:

```
<form method= POST action="{{ url_for('input_ext') }}">
            <table>
              {% for field in form %}
                <tr>
                            <td>{{ field.label }}*</td><td>{{ field }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </table>
<input id = "generate" name="generate" type=submit value=Next></form>
```

Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from model import InputForm

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
#select interface and for selected interfaces pullup circuit info
def provideinput():
    global devices
    devices = ''
    form = InputForm(request.form)
    return render_template("utctime.html", form=form)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host="10.23.102.116",port=82)
```

Problem is that, i get time in UTC and is not updating to current UTC value whenever i reload page.It stays same as i start run python code.
Anything wrong in defining DateTimeField ?

Changed as below,still no luck:

```
  stime = DateTimeField(label='Start time(EDT)', validators=[validators.InputRequired()], format="%d%b%Y %H:%M",
                          default=datetime.today)
    etime = DateTimeField(label='End time(EDT)', validators=[validators.InputRequired()], format="%d%b%Y %H:%M",
                          default=datetime.today)
```

Comment: etime = DateTimeField(label='End time(EDT)', validators=[validators.InputRequired()], format="%d%b%Y %H:%M",
                          default=datetime.today)  -> Did like this still it is same no change in time after reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in [wtforms+flask today's date as a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421166/wtformsflask-todays-date-as-a-default-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Someone quoted this earlier. My bad i was editing at wrong place.

changed to :

```
stime = DateTimeField(label='Start time(EDT)',validators=[validators.InputRequired()],format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M",default= datetime.utcnow)
    etime = DateTimeField(label='End time(EDT)',validators=[validators.InputRequired()],format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M",default= datetime.utcnow)
```